# How to: confirm alert for cloaked external link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site where all of the external links are cloaked. In order to identify these external links I have added the slug "/go/" to the end of the domain. So taking this site as an example, instead of using "example.com" as the href leading away from stackoverflow.com, we would use "stackoverflow.com/go/example".

How would I create jQuery to search each href on the page, and if it contains "/go/", create a popup window that lets the user choose to stay or leave the site.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").on("click", function() {
        if($(this).attr("href").indexOf("page_id") == -1) {
            return confirm("Link Disclaimer: Bla bla bla...");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

↑ This example will lead you away from the site if the domain is different, it doesn't work based on a slug match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will show a confirm box for all `a` tags whose `href` attribute contains `/go/` in them

```
$("a[href*='/go/']").on("click", function() {
    return confirm("Link Disclaimer: Bla bla bla...");
});
```

Comment: Though both of these are working examples, I chose this one for it's simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be simple enough, following on from your example like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").on("click", function() {
        if($(this).attr("href").indexOf('http://example.com/go/') != -1) {
            return confirm("Link Disclaimer: Bla bla bla...");
        }
    });
});
```

Unless I'm missing the point?

#### Explanation:

On click of a link, if the link's href has the `http://example.com/go/` in the title (i.e. `indexOf` doesn't return -1) show the disclaimer.

#### Demo

http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/emBONX